# MGTwitterEngine reply to a tweet not working

Tags: objective-c, ios4, twitter, mgtwitterengine, reply

I am using `MGTwitterEngine`

using this code for reply a tweet

`[[twitter sendUpdate:text inReplyTo:message_ID] retain];`

But it works as a normal tweet. not as a reply of any specific tweet.

Any idea.

Comment: i am having the same problem.
have you managed to solved it?